# Can I change Apple Music radio stations so it doesn't buffer when I pause listening?

Tags: music, catalina, apple-music, streaming, itunes-radio

I use the Apple Music app on Catalina to stream radio stations.

When I hit the stop/pause button the streams pauses and buffers. If I hit play again, it resumes the playback at the old location.

Is there any way to jump to the current stream and drop the buffered audio?